# Format by template in Scala

Tags: c#, scala

In C# I can do:

```
  private string baseUrlFormat = "https://{0}.maindomain.com"
  public string LoginUrl {
    get {
      return String.Format(baseUrlFormat, "subdomain1");
    }
  }
```

I can't figure out how to do the same thing in Scala:

```
  private val baseUrlFormat = "https://???.maindomain.com"
  val loginUrl = ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't exactly fit your example, but Starting in Scala 2.10, you can do [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/string-interpolation.html):

```
val subDomain = "sd"
val url = s"$subDomain.maindomain.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format strings using the format method:

```
private val baseUrlFormat = "https://%s.maindomain.com"
val loginUrl = baseUrlFormat.format("subdomain1")
```